Efficient way to search through files in VBA
I need to get the "largest" title of a bunch of files in a folder, but with VBA it takes way too long to loop through all the files to get all their names to determine the largest filename (because the folder has 9000 files).
Is there a reliable way to have VBA look at the sorted files?
I.e., if I always get the first 20 files, will that always be the first 20 by date, or alphabetically? Or am I sacrificing reliability by not looking at all of the files?
EDIT
Here is my code currently:
Dim path As String
Dim i As Integer

path = Dir("C:\xyz\*.*")

Do While path <> "" And i < 20

    ' My code here

    i = i + 1
Loop


I'm using a path with wildcards... so "C:\xyz*.*" and then looping while that path <> ""...

There are 2 ways to loop over files using VBA, one is using Dir (which you probably use as you mention wildcards), the other is using the FileSystemObject. Both return the files in no reliable order (as files are not stored in any order).

What is the largest filename? The filename which has the most number of characters? Additonally, looping with Dir is quite fast, at least in my experience, even for folders with 9000 files in it. Are you sure that there are not any other reasons for the poor performance?

At least to my experience using Dir to loop through files in a given folder is not that slow.
For example the following code will give you the largest file in terms of size in a given directory. However, the code has the drawback that Filelen will return a negative number for files larger than 2GB, i.e. the code will not work in this case.
Sub testit()

    Dim fileName As String, maxfileName As String
    Dim pathName As String
    Dim maxSize As Long
    Dim nextSize As Long

    pathName = "C:\TEMP\"
    fileName = Dir(pathName & "*")

    Do While fileName <> ""
        
        nextSize = FileLen(pathName & fileName)
        If maxSize < nextSize Then
            maxSize = FileLen(pathName & fileName)
            maxfileName = fileName
        End If
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print maxfileName & ": " & maxSize

End Sub

If you need the length of the filename, i.e the number of characters, just use
Do While fileName <> ""
    
    nextSize = Len(fileName)
    If maxSize < nextSize Then
        maxSize = Len(fileName)
        maxfileName = fileName
    End If
    fileName = Dir
Loop

Debug.Print maxfileName & ": " & maxSize

PS Tested the code in a folder with around 5000 files. I cannot confirm that VBA takes way too long.
Update: Based on a comment it might be the case that the OP would like to get the first x (x=10,20,...) files which have the longest filename starting with the filename with the most number of characters.
One could achieve that with the following code
Sub getIt()
    
    Dim pathname As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    pathname = "D:\TMP\FILES\"
    fileName = Dir(pathname, vbNormal)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vdat As Variant
    ReDim vdat(1 To noFiles(pathname), 1 To 2)
    
    i = 1
    Do While fileName <> ""
        vdat(i, 1) = fileName
        vdat(i, 2) = Len(fileName)
        fileName = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    ' sort by the column with the length of the filename
    vdat = WorksheetFunction.Sort(vdat, 2, -1)
    
    ' print the first 20 hits, starting with the filename
    ' with the most characters
    For i = 1 To 20
        Debug.Print vdat(i, 1), vdat(i, 2)
    Next i
    
End Sub


Function noFiles(dirName As String) As Long
    ' Returns the number of files in a give folder
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        noFiles = .GetFolder(dirName).Files.Count
    End With
End Function

Using Dir did not cause any performance issue for me. The code completed in less than 1s even for a folder with 10.000 files in it

Gets tricky if you want more than 1 file

@FunThomas: Not really, I think.  But if that's what the OP is after then I did not get it. Anyway, the code the OP posted does not really show anything what he is after. But maybe your guess was better than mine.  Apart from that, capturing data from a shell command is tricky and often unreliable.

An operating system doesn't store files in any particular order. Instead, the commands used to list the files do the sorting, eg the dir-command using the -O-switch, or the windows explorer (by clicking on the title of the column you want to sort).
The usual way is to read all files into an array and sort this array, see for example Sorted list of file names in a folder in VBA?
Unfortunately, you don't define "largest" - largest by Name, by Date, by Size? If by anything else than name, you need to put some extra effort to read also the property and use that as sorting criteria. Also, even if sorting by name, you can have surprises as for example file100.jpg will be sorted before file99.jpg because sorting is done on alphabetical order.
As you already mentioned, reading (and sorting) all files can be slow if you have a lot of files in your folder. The following might be an alternative if you really want to have the files purely sorted by name. It issues a Dir-command with sort option and reads the result. This is usually faster, but be warned that it might fail (or needs some extra work, honestly IDK) if your file names contain characters that are not plain 7bit ASCII.
The code to issue a cmd and read the output is basically from Capture output value from a shell command in VBA?
Public Function getDirList(filepattern As String) As String
    ' Const SortDirCmd = "dir /ON /B"  ' Ascending
    Const SortDirCmd = "dir /O-N /B"   ' Descending
    
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = shell.exec("cmd.exe /c " & SortDirCmd & " """ & filepattern & """")
    Dim result
    result = cmd.StdOut.ReadAll
    cmd.Terminate
   
    getDirList = result
End Function

I tested it with
Sub test()
    Const maxFiles = 20
    
    Dim lines() As String
    lines = Split(getDirList("C:\Users\<funThomas>\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*"), vbCrLf)
    Debug.Print UBound(lines) + 1 & " files"
    Dim i As Long, max As Long
    max = IIf(maxFiles - 1 < UBound(lines), maxFiles - 1, UBound(lines))
    For i = 0 To max
        Debug.Print i, lines(i)
    Next
End Sub

It runs in a fraction of a second - however with the drawback that a file with the name zzä.txt came back as zz„.txt - and that you have a short flicker on the screen when the command window is executed.
(Type Help Dir at the command prompt to list other options to sort files)

Still trying to figure out why Shell commands crash Excel at work, but work perfectly fine on my home PC.  This is the fastest way I've found, but just doesn't work on the work network.
